# Abelian von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a family of commutative normal operators which is closed under adjoint. clearly $M\subset M'$, but I do not know why $M'\subset M^{''}$? and how can conclude that $M^{''}$ is abelian?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that $M'\subset M''$, for example consider $M=\{I\}$ the identity operator. To show that $M''$ is commutative though just use the fact that it is the WOT closure of the  algebra generated by $M$ (the Double Commutant theorem.)